# Change a label in a View to a div?

Tags: theming, views

How can I change the label for a view to be a div instead? Here is my HTML, its the "Sort by" label I need to change.

```
<form class="ctools-auto-submit-full-form views-exposed-form-author-content-panel-pane-1 ctools-auto-submit-processed" action="/" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-author-content-panel-pane-1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div>

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('views_exposed_form') -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php' -->
<div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
          <div id="edit-sort-bef-combine-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-sort_bef_combine">
                        <div class="views-widget">
                    <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-sort-bef-combine">
  <label for="edit-sort-bef-combine">Sort by </label>
 <div id="edit-sort-bef-combine" class="form-radios"><ul class="btn-group"><li class="btn-group__item"><a href="http://localhost.site.com/news/author?sort_bef_combine=created%20DESC" class="btn btn--sort btn--active">Date</a></li><li class="btn-group__item"><a href="http://localhost.site.com/news/author-dobie?sort_bef_combine=value%20DESC" class="btn btn--sort">Popular</a></li></ul><input type="hidden" name="sort_bef_combine" value="created DESC"></div>
</div>
        </div>
              </div>
                    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
      <button class="ctools-use-ajax ctools-auto-submit-click js-hide btn form-submit" id="edit-submit-author-content" name="" value="Apply">Apply</button>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'sites/all/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php' -->

</div></form>
```

The template responsible is `views-exposed-form.tpl.php`. Within the template the code below prints the form:

```
    <div class="views-widget findhere ">
      <?php print $widget->widget; ?>
    </div>
```

I've done a `dsm` on the $widget but the array just contains the full HTML.

Ive looked at `hook_form_alter` and done a `dsm` on this but in the full form array I still cant see a way to change the form label to a different element.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using better exposed filter module, it has option to configure the sorting label

[image]

so instead of Sort By `<div>Sort by</div>` it will not replace the label but give you a nested div if that works for you.

Comment: I dont understand your answer. Yes I am using better exposed filters module. I already have the those options populated. This puts the text "Sort by" within a label element which is what I need to change.

Comment: I meant simply replace the text Sort by, with <div>Sort By</div> this will not replace the <label> but will give you a nested <div> inside <label>, if it helps you.

Comment: Ah im afraid not. I need to remove the label element completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews)

**Description form This module page:**

> This Views plugin makes unformatted styles, field row styles and other
> output more readily configurable without needing to override template
> files. Instead of overriding row style templates for views where you
> want to specify different HTML elements (tags) and class attributes,
> you can specify these inside the Views UI and avoid overriding
> templates for each view.
>
> Some of Semantics Views functionality can be done in Views, but Views
> is restricted to use only predefined HTML element and can only style
> each Field but not wrap rows with any HTML you like.

And Also you can override `views-view-fields.tpl.php`

Comment: Thanks for the link. However id rather not load a new module just to fix one thing.

Comment: @jdln your welcome, I update my answer, you can also override  `views-view-fields.tpl.php`